# Passing Object Model to action using location.href

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, knockout.js

I am using knockout in my MVC application.
There is a requirement for showing up a excel file with some data inside it.
There is a model at client side, which is populated on some action (it looks like this)

```
$o.ProductsModel = function () {
    self = this;
    self.Products = ko.observableArray([]);
};
```

When user clicks the excel button, I call this

```
var Inputs = {orderNum: 33, details: ko.toJS(self.ProductsModel)};

location.href = 'Products/DownloadExcel?' + $.param(Inputs, true);
```

The action method looks like this

```
public virtual ActionResult DownloadExcelDirect(string orderNum, Details details)
{
...prepare the excel
return File(excel, "application/ms-excel", "invoices.csv");
}
```

The problem is

> **orderNum** parameter is passed properly to the action method but the **Details parameter is coming up null.**
>
> Am I missing something ? Is it possible to send a list of strings / object as parameter to location.href ??

Comment: How is your `Details` class looks like?

Comment: Well, the ViewModel.ProductsModel.Products is same as Details class.

Comment: public class Details
    {
        public ICollection<MyObject> Products { get; set; }
    }
And in client side also there is MyObject with same format/properties.

Comment: Is there any other way to pass a list of object ? Please suggest, I can change to that best methodology ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: firstly, it should be `ko.toJSON`. asp.net will auto serialize that. but you need to ensure that object type is the same. what do you pass to products model?

Comment: I get this error when I use ko.toJSON()
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

And Products model is populated with MyObject as defined exactly same as it is in .cs class.

Comment: Plus, more importantly a thing to notice : 
when this - ko.toJS(self.ProductsModel);
is passed to ajax post as parameter, it gets called perfectly but with location.href, its null.